# After publish Blazor app I get error "Invalid object name"

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a Blazor application (Wasm), ASP.NET hosted (.net 5). When debugging everything works fine. But if I publish the application and run the compiled EXE, I get the following error. I am using two databases in the application and the error mentions the second one.
Could someone point me in the direction of what the problem is? Connection strings are set the same for debugging and publishing versions.

Thank you for your help.

```
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
      Failed executing DbCommand (7ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT [a].[Id], [a].[City], [a].[Company], [a].[CompanyShort], [a].[Country], [a].[Note], [a].[Street]
      FROM [AisCustomer] AS [a]
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[10100]
      An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'Vks.Server.Data.AisDbContext'.      Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'AisCustomer'.
         at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__169_0(Task`1 result)
         at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
         at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__277_0(Object obj)
         at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(DbContext _, Boolean result, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
      ClientConnectionId:99e2a360-bb51-4a54-ac4a-ba6addc7cfd4
      Error Number:208,State:1,Class:16
      Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'AisCustomer'.
         at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__169_0(Task`1 result)
         at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
         at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__277_0(Object obj)
         at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(DbContext _, Boolean result, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
      ClientConnectionId:99e2a360-bb51-4a54-ac4a-ba6addc7cfd4
      Error Number:208,State:1,Class:16
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
      Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'AisCustomer'.
         at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__169_0(Task`1 result)
         at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
         at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__277_0(Object obj)
         at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(DbContext _, Boolean result, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToDictionaryAsync[TSource,TKey,TElement](IQueryable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToDictionaryAsync[TSource,TKey,TElement](IQueryable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Vks.Server.Controllers.OrderController.GetAll() in C:\Users\hladik\Documents\Source Code\vks\Server\Controllers\OrderController.cs:line 72
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, IEndpointRouter router, IUserSession session, IEventService events, IBackChannelLogoutService backChannelLogoutService)
         at IdentityServer4.Hosting.MutualTlsEndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemes)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at IdentityServer4.Hosting.BaseUrlMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.MapWhenMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)
      ClientConnectionId:99e2a360-bb51-4a54-ac4a-ba6addc7cfd4
      Error Number:208,State:1,Class:16
```

Update:
In both cases, the appsettings.json are the same, except for the IdentityServer section. There I added a Key section (link to the certificate).

```
// appsettings.json
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=testmachine;Database=vks;User=myUser;Password=myPasswd",
    "AISConnection": "Server=testmachine;Database=ais;User=myUser;Password=myPasswd"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "IdentityServer": {
    "Key": {
        "Type": "Store",
        "StoreName": "My",
        "StoreLocation": "CurrentUser",
        "Name": "CN=VksCertificate" 
    },
    "Clients": {
      "Vks.Client": {
        "Profile": "IdentityServerSPA"
      }
    }
  },
"AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Comment: It's saying the object name doesn't exist in SQL - are there any other differences between publish and debug such as maybe which account is authenticating to the database?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Blazor. The error says the table doesn't exist in the database. Did you deploy the database as well? Are you connecting to the wrong database perhaps? If you use EF Core Migrations did you execute them?

Comment: If I go from debug to publish, do I need to reapply migrations to the same database? I assumed that if the migration was the same, it didn't have to be reapplied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for the advice and although it's embarrassing, I'll put the solution to my problem here. I didn't notice that after publishing the app, three appsettings files (appsettings.json, appsettings.development.json, appsettings.production.json) are created in the folder publish and that was my problem. I had the wrong database name in the appsettings.production.json file. I have no idea why, I didn't know about this file at all.